# Copy cells from one Workbook (non-specific) to another (specific)

Tags: vba, excel

Okay, so I'm trying to create an order log for a business (employee usage).

I have a form set out where multiple users can access/input all the information needed. It prints into an Excel spreadsheet for one person to open and place orders from. Sometimes a user might want to copy an order line from a previous year's log (there are 4 so far), so I'm trying to incorporate that into the current log.

I'm having trouble with referencing another workbook that the user has opened and copying the information into a userform opened in the current log. I have this:

```
Private Sub cmdCopy_Click()

Dim rowRef As Integer, colItem As Integer, colSup As Integer, colCatNum As Integer, colQty As Integer, colUnit As Integer, colCat As Integer

'stores row of selected order from old order log successfully
rowRef = ActiveCell.row

'I'm trying to find which column has which headers as the logs aren't consistent
For x = 2 To 9
    If ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Cells(2, x).Text = "Item" Then
        colItem = x
    ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Cells(2, x).Text = "Supplier" Then
        colSup = x
    ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Cells(2, x).Text = "Catalogue #" Then
        colCatNum = x
    ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Cells(2, x).Text = "Qty" Then
        colQty = x
    ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Cells(2, x).Text = "Unit" Then
        colUnit = x
    ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Cells(2, x).Text = "Category" Then
        colCat = x
    End If
Next x

'fills information into userform
txtItem.Text = Sheet1.Cells(rowRef, colItem).Text
txtSup.Text = Sheet1.Cells(rowRef, colSup).Value
txtCatNum.Text = Sheet1.Cells(rowRef, colCatNum).Value
txtQty.Text = Sheet1.Cells(rowRef, colQty).Value
cboUnit.Text = Sheet1.Cells(rowRef, colUnit).Value
cboCat.Text = Sheet1.Cells(rowRef, colCat).Value

End Sub
```

So what I want to happen is:

1. User opens current order log
2. User presses ActiveX button to open frmOrderLog
3. a) User enters information manually
      b) User copies information from current year's log
      c) User minimizes window, opens previous year's log, selects a cell, and in the userform presses "Copy Order" button which then copies the information from corresponding cells from the previous year's order log into the corresponding text boxes/combo boxes in the form within the current year's order log

If there is any requirement for clarification, let me know. I'm sorry if this is in the forums already, but using my search terms I could not find answers that helped.

Comment: Please tag appropriately - it looks like something Microsoft/Windows-related but who knows ?

Comment: Sorry, I am extremely new to this site, and adding tags to posts in general. I have been assigned this task because I have the most experience with VBA, but still not much.

Comment: No problem - it looks like you've got the hang of tags now!

Comment: FYI: `Dim rowRef, colItem, colSup, colCatNum, colQty, colUnit, colCat As Integer` does not define all those variables as integer. It defines the last one as integer, and the rest as variant. To get them all as integer, you would need to have `Dim rowRef As Integer, colItem As Integer, colSup As Integer, colCatNum As Integer, colQty As Integer, colUnit As Integer, colCat As Integer`

Comment: Thanks, will change that. Also, how did you edit it to look like code (highlights If, EndIf, Dim, As Integer, etc)? I could not get it to work when I posted.

Comment: Since presumably this isn't working, what is happening when you run the code?

Comment: " Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method " on line:
If ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Cells(2, x).Text = "Item" Then

Comment: a `code` block is signified by 4 spaces - by removing the `<pre>` tag you had, it was then recognized as code, and could be formatted correctly - you can use the **{}** button in the edit box to format highlighted text as code

Comment: I tried that, but it wasn't doing the indentations properly until I put <pre></pre> in. Maybe an issue with IE (since I'm using an old version)? Either way, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a simple syntax issue to me:

you want to change:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Cells(2, x).Text = "Item" Then
```

To:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, x).Text = "Item" Then
```

The Sheet1 syntax didn't work for me.

And obviously you want to make the same change wherever else Sheet1 occurs.

Comment: That was it, thanks so much! I'm still pretty new at VBA, glad to know people are so willing to help with pretty basic mistakes!

Comment: No problem, it's actually something that, syntactically, is a little confusing. Because With Sheet1 (put code here) End With - this is actually completely OK. But it seems like the ActiveWorkbook object requires you to use the Sheets(1) syntax. They should probably make that more consistent in the language. Although as with many things they probably have their reasons.